# Why mipmap folder not show in suggestion of XML Android Studio?

Tags: android, mipmaps, android-mipmap

Currently I tried to use `ic_launcher` from  **mipmap** folder. As I used to with suggestions, I pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd> after **@** but didn't get any suggestions for **mipmap**

Is there any problem or I miss something to get Suggestions? Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem i upgrade my Android Studio Version 1.5.1 to 2.1.1 and now i can show mipmap folder in suggestion.

[image]